# Does keep posting Quran translations on the Internet, can make a threat on the original Arabic script in the future?

Tags: discussion, quran, arabic

I understand it's almost impossible  to lose the original script as we have millions of copies of the same exact Arabic book (on paper and digitally and in the savers(حفظة) hearts) and we have Islamic organizations that must audit and review every copy before it's printed.

But I'm talking about keep posting and using the translations every day, doesn't this can make generations of Muslims in the future who give a translation book a superiority over the Quran.

Let us agree on some points

- a translation is, well *a translation*, it's not the Quran (It's not what Allah has revealed to the profit Muhammad )

This is Quran

> الْحَمْدُ لِلَّهِ رَبِّ الْعَالَمِينَ

But this is not Quran

> [All] praise is [due] to Allah, Lord of the worlds

- a translation will MUST have some differences in the meaning, no matter how was the translator specific and good.
- the reality has proved that it's the interpretation(understanding) that affects our lives, it's not the script.

based on the 3 points I laid, doesn't this can lead to a Muslim in the future that doing something wrong based on a translation that conflicts with the Arabic script, and he **ignores** the meaning of the Arabic verse and keep the meaning of the translation?

### I suggest ..

Making it a habit and instead of posting [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/53535/can-a-muslim-who-follows-ahl-al-sunnah-wa-al-jamaah-also-follow-some-sufi-teach#comment90762_53535) on the internet (*the comment is mine BTW*)

> "And whatever the Messenger has given you - take; and what he has forbidden you - refrain from. And fear Allah ; indeed, Allah is severe in penalty".[Quran 59:7](https://quran.com/59/7)

Isn't it better to post this

> "وَمَا آتَاكُمُ الرَّسُولُ فَخُذُوهُ وَمَا نَهَاكُمْ عَنْهُ فَانتَهُوا ۚ وَاتَّقُوا اللَّهَ ۖ إِنَّ اللَّهَ شَدِيدُ الْعِقَابِ".[Quran 59:7](https://quran.com/59/7)

*(unless offcurse the context needs a translation, e.g someone asks for a translation)*

Comment: This question looks like a better fit for our [meta]. Certainly posting English translation of the qur'an might be an issue on this site as many good questions which certainly need explanation from the Arabic perspective don't make anymore sense when we use a translation, as it includes the interpretation one may try to explain. But the site's language is English so it is a must to post in English in first place. Whether you post in both languages is up to you.

Comment: @Medi1Saif I actually tried to search for Islam Meta, but I thought there is no Meta for islam.se. Can I delete this question from here and post it on Meta before someone answers it  ? BTW, I feel that islam.se is safe when I see you Media1Saif, I wish you get 1M rep here and become moderator for your entire life, ربنا يكرمك ❤️ 

Comment: Just FYI, this site is not only for Muslim but also for everyone, including non-Muslim. Thus, I don't think everyone can understand Arabic. A better compromise is to provide the original writing and the translated version (also, always include the translation source if possible). Also, somewhat related: [Please tag your Bible verses with the version of the Bible you are quoting from](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3545), [What translations do we accept?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/566) (not to push an opinion, but hopefully might help in discussing this topic)